# Sliding photos inside footer wordpress

Tags: javascript, footer, sliding

I have about 30 different logos and I have to put them all in the footer which should slide those images like in this page footer http://laravel.com/, where background is slowly sliding by. How I can do that?

Comment: Your question is too generic and you should at least attempt to create what you need without asking others to do it for you. What have you tried so far? Have you tried any sliders yet? What is your code?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I hope that there is a jquery plugin or something. Lets be more simple, can I do any content, text, picture, ect written in same <div> make slowly sliding left, like in that page.

Comment: Yes. My favorite slider is Flex Slider by WooThemes. There is a free one that is really good but may be too advanced. They also have a WordPress Slider plugin as well but it costs $29. Check them out here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code with jQuery:

HTML :

```
<div id="silde">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#silde{
    height:191px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(http://laravel.com/assets/img/quotes.jpg);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var posi = 0 ;
    setInterval(function(){
        posi++;
        $("#silde").css("background-position",posi+'px 0');
        }, 200);
});
```

and you can use `posi++` to move right, `posi--` to move left.
and you can see the sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bbykut3/1/

Comment: Its my css code `.home.page .footerclass{
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(http://laravel.com/assets/img/quotes.jpg);
    background-position: 0 0;
}` it shows picture, but that picture not moving, what should I change in JS code?

Comment: "#silde" change to '.home.page .footerclass' .

Comment: Everything works with my code in http://jsfiddle.net, but it still doesn't move on page.. JS code I added inside <head><script></script></head>

Comment: send a new question and copy your code in the question and send the question url here.

Comment: it's work fine and do you sure the jquery load in your page ?

Comment: yea, I added that JQ code inside head page between <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: So yesterday I made background in footer moving in my page successfully. Now what I need to make single picture moving the same, do you think its hard to change a code a bit? Heres fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bbykut3/3/